# Oxidation States?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, analytical-chemistry

Metals in low Oxidation states are usually reducing agents. Is there any example of a metal in zero Oxidation state acting as an oxidizing agent.

Answer (score 1):

As with pretty much every "is there ______?" in chemistry, the answer is yes, there is.

Of course, using the pure *metal* itself as an oxidising agent would be really tough. However, if you use certain tricks to stabilise the negative oxidation state, it is possible. For example, π-acceptor ligands such as $\ce{CO}$ withdraw electron density from the metal. So, $\ce{M[(CO)_n]^m-}$ complexes are stable for certain choices of $\ce{M}$, $n$, and $m$. For more details see: [18 Electron Rule For Determining the Stability of Transition Metal Complexes](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58052/18-electron-rule-for-determining-the-stability-of-transition-metal-complexes)

Consider $\ce{[V(CO)6]}$, a 17-electron complex. It would be quite happy to accept another electron to become $[\ce{V(CO)6}]^-$. This reduction can be achieved with sodium metal. So, here vanadium(0) is acting as an oxidising agent; it is itself reduced to vanadium(−1).

These examples are not incredibly common, but it can happen.

Answer (score 0):

If metal is in 0 oxidation state would get oxidized, then it would have to achieve a negative oxidation state since it would have to itself get reduced. Since it is a metal, it would have a really low reduction potential. If the reducing agent has a really high reduction potential, then I think it might be possible ( you will have to check the reduction potential values for that )